# Only getting response codes, but not actual response, from OAuth::AccessToken

Tags: ruby, oauth, twitter-oauth

In my `User` model, I have the following code:

```
def twitter_client
  OAuth::AccessToken.new(twitter_oauth, self.access_token_key, self.access_token_secret)
end

def twitter_oauth
  OAuth::Consumer.new(Twitter::Login.consumer_key, Twitter::Login.secret, :site => Twitter::Login.site)
end
```

This way I can call User#twitter_client like so:

```
current_user.twitter_client.post('/statuses/update.xml', {'status' => 'foooo', 'Accept' => 'application/xml'})
```

This works well, and actually does update the status, and returns the following:

```
#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

This really is not a problem for updating statuses. However, when I want to get the latest tweets, all I get is a response code object, without the actual content from the response:

```
current_user.twitter_client.get('/statuses/user_timeline.xml', {'Accept' => 'application/xml'})
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

This returned object is just an instance of `Net::HTTPOK` and contains no tweet data.

How do I get the tweet data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about...?

```
res = current_user.twitter_client.get('/statuses/user_timeline.xml', {'Accept' => 'application/xml'})

puts res.body
```

Comment: obvious is better than obscure! (at least you've got a chance then:)